# MS TS Web Access (https://localhost/RDWeb) not functional after upgrading to IE11 (from IE9)

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Can login in Explorer, however when upgrading from IE9 to IE11, I get the following message:

> Browser Not Supported
>
> This Web browser is not supported by RD Web Access. RD Web Access
>   requires Internet Explorer 6.0 or later.
>
> You can download the latest version of Internet Explorer from the
>   Windows Update Web site.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: addressed above

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is your answer: http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows/127594-ie11-rd-web-access.html (or this for more unrecommended options: http://www.concurrency.com/infrastructure/ie11-browser-supported-rdweb-2008-r2/ )

> If you have upgrade to IE 11 you may recieve the following error when
>   trying to use RD Web access.
>
> Error: Browser Not Supported - This Web browser is not supported by RD
>   Web Access. RD Web Access requires Internet Explorer 6.0 or later. You
>   can download the latest version of Internet Explorer from the Windows
>   Update Web site
>
> Resolution:
>
> First of all this fix ONLY works on RDS Gateway servers with 2008 R2
>   SP1 installed. If you try it on a server without SP1 it will get rid
>   of the error but you wont see any remote apps.
>
> 1. Login to the RDS Gateway server
> 2. Open Up IIS Management Console.
> 3. Branch out the sites and then left click on RDweb. On the right hand side double click on HTTP Response Headers.
> 4. On the right hand pane now right click and select Add…
> 5. On the box that appears enter : Name : X-UA-Compatible Value : IE=9
>
> Now do a IISRESET on the server and you should be good to go..

Comment: Thanks! I found a workaround, probably the same one in your link. It's a setting change on IIS

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). In particular you need to quote correctly. I've fixed you answer this time. Also you don't need to add "edit" or "/cd" (your initials), this is just "noise". The edit history is available for anyone to see what changes have been made.